# Modular arithmetic with huge modulus?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, computer-science

When the dividend is some huge power but the modulus is not so big, I can use modular exponentiation. But how can I compute the residue when the modulus is, for example, $2^{107} - 1$, a Mersenne prime, as in
$$8934^{3167} \bmod{(2^{107} -1)}$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such calculations occur routinely in cryptography with moduli ten times as long (or more) as your 107 bits.

They are out of reach of realistic pencil-and-paper calculations, of course, but can be done without too much trouble on a computer with the straightforward implementations of algorithms (such as exponentiation-by-squaring) that work by hand in smaller cases.

In applications where efficiency is important, some extra performance can be squeezed out using tricks such as [Montgomery reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_reduction) and [efficient multiplication algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fast_multiplication_algorithms_for_large_inputs).